# Infinite loop when trying to remove item while iterative through list C#

Tags: c#, list, loops, generics

I'm using a generic List in C# to implement a simple algorithm and there are some operations need to perform in a loop. Below is the code snippet.

```
 public static void ReverseLevelOrder(TreeNode root)
  {
    if (root == null) return;
    List<TreeNode> q = new List<TreeNode>();
    List<TreeNode> stk = new List<TreeNode>();
    TreeNode temp = root;
    q.Add(temp);
    while(q.Count > 0)
    {
      TreeNode currNode = q.ElementAt(0);
      q.RemoveAt(0);
      stk.Add(currNode);
      if (temp.left != null)
      {
        q.Add(temp.left);
      }
      if (temp.right != null)
      {
        q.Add(temp.right);
      }
    }
   
    // some code
```

When I run the code, the loop is endless. I could not figure out what cause this problem. Am I missing something? My knowledge in C# is still bad, so please point the problem out to me.

`EDIT`: the definition of data is the Binary Tree with 7 nodes:

```
      TreeNode node = new TreeNode(1);
      node.left = new TreeNode(2);
      node.right = new TreeNode(3);
      node.left.left = new TreeNode(4);
      node.left.right = new TreeNode(5);
      node.right.left = new TreeNode(6);
      node.right.right = new TreeNode(7);
```

Comment: Without knowing your data it is difficult to say for sure, but what I see is that within your loop it loops like you remove from "q" and add to "q" for each iteration.  Therefore, as you check for q.Count >0 then it will never be zero.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith Thank you for your comment. The data is just a binary tree with 7 nodes: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.

Comment: What is the definition of `TreeNode`?

Comment: I aimed to use a list as queue to perform nodes of tree in level order and store it in auxiliary stack, and then print it in reversed level order.

Comment: @Steeeve I updated my post included tree nodes.

Comment: Yes, but what is TreeNode? I only found two of them, both are related to TreeView class in WinForms and Web.UI. Your TreeNode object is obviously none of them.

Comment: @Steeeve this is a simple implementation of an algorithm that Im trying! Properties of TreeNode are just: left, right, data.

Comment: @Steeeve I just confuse with the loop! In Java, it must be fine. But in C# Im not sure.

Comment: Well, I don't know how the Java TreeNode class is implemented, but without knowing how your TreeNode class (or struct?) implementation looks like, is hard to evaluate the code. What does the constructor accepting an int? Can the left and right properties ever be null?

Answer (score 1):

your code in these lines :

```
`if (temp.left != null)
  {
    q.Add(temp.left);
  }
  if (temp.right != null)
  {
    q.Add(temp.right);
  }`
```

go to infinity are you sure for q.Add(left) or q.Add(right)

Comment: because in these line tree added to list from right and left and again again ...

Comment: @K_ng you should use currentNode instead of temp in the while loop, in current code you don't change temp value so it always that same root node